# GRE question about logs

Tags: logarithms

So I have a question about a step they make in the GRE subject book.

Finding derivative of $\arcsin($log$(x)))$

So I know how to do it, its just chain rule but there's one step I really do not understand:

they go from

$$(\log(\sqrt{e}))^2=\frac{1}{4}$$

I get that

$$\log(\sqrt{e}) = \frac{1}{2}\log e$$

but I thought

$$\ln e=1$$

and that regular log of $e$ is like .4 something...

Am I missing something?

Comment: $\log$ is commonly used to denote $\ln$.

Comment: ok thanks! that clears things up a lot. Not a fan of this ambiguity.

Comment: I am assuming that the author let $\log = \log_e =\ln$. Then

$$(\log(\sqrt{e}))^2=(\log e^{1/2})^2=\left(\frac12 \log e\right)^2=\left(\frac 12\right)^2 = \frac 14$$

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Most math books will use $\log$ instead of $\ln$, whereas the opposite is true for physics/engineering.

Comment: yes as apposed to base $10$, thought the same after @player3236 said that

Comment: @rubikscube09 thanks!